# DIV SPAN SWITCHING

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a problem to make div switching.

```
<div id="swapper-first" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
        This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
    <p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
        This div displayed when the link was clicked.
    </p>
</div>


<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round" href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other')"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: 1. Spans do not have hrefs, use onclick or obtrusively 2. Where is SwapDivsWithClick 3. Why not onchange of the checkbox and have a label?

Comment: `<span href="...">` isn't gonna work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Describe details.

Comment: Would you be willing to tell us what your problem is?

Comment: Vote to close as **off topic** _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Comment: You should use `onchange` on the checkbox, rather than `onclick` of the span. Otherwise, clicking the checkbox itself will toggle the checkbox but not your divs, which I assume is what you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <a class="slider round" onclick="SwapDivsWithClick()"></a>
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SwapDivsWithClick(){
        var first = document.getElementById("swapper-first");
        var second = document.getElementById("swapper-other");
        first.style.display = 'none';
        second.style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>
```